# Errors while running ctest

Tags: ctest

When we try running ctest with Catch2 test cases, we got the Errors while running CTest in the last line but the test cases ran properly.

After adding the ParseAndAddCatchTests.cmake in CMakeLists.txt.

```
enable_testing()
include(ParseAndAddCatchTests.cmake)
ParseAndAddCatchTests(TauTest)
```

Run the test case using 'ctest' command. We got the following error after execution of tests.

`Errors while running CTest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems test cases failing. That's why I got the error `Errors while running CTest`